# Unable to Format Output Text File to Desired Form using "write" function Python

Tags: python

I am unable to format the output of my text file as I want it. I have fooled around with this for almost an hour, to no avail, and it's driving me mad. I want the first four floats to be on one line, and the next 10 values to be delimited by new lines.

```
    if not (debug_flag>0):
        text_file = open("Markov.txt", "w")
        text_file.write("%.2f,%.2f,%.2f,%.2f" % (prob_not_to_not,prob_not_to_occured, prob_occured_to_not, prob_occured_to_occured))

        for x in xrange(0,10):
             text_file.write("\n%d" % markov_sampler(final_probability))

        text_file.close()
```

Does anyone know what the issue is? The output I'm getting is all on 1 line.

Comment: That code should work... but we can't test it because its not runnable. Can you change this to write hard-coded floats? You want something that demonstrates the problem but that we can run to test.

Comment: I cooked up an example using hard-coded floats and it worked fine. I cannot reproduce the problem.

Comment: If you still have the problem, do `print(open("Markov.txt"), "rb").read())` - mentioning that you are posting a `bytes` representation of the contents. Then we can see exactly what is there.

Answer (score 1):

You have to put the line feed at the end of the first line for it to work.
Also your text editor may be configure to have the \r\n end of line( if you are using notepad ), in wich case you should be seeing everything in the same line.

The code with the desired output may look something like this

```
if not (debug_flag>0):
    text_file = open("Markov.txt", "w")
    text_file.write("%.2f,%.2f,%.2f,%.2f\n" % (prob_not_to_not,prob_not_to_occured, prob_occured_to_not, prob_occured_to_occured))

    for x in xrange(0,10):
         text_file.write("%d\n" % markov_sampler(final_probability))

    text_file.close()
```

Comment: Writing `\n` at the start of the other strings works. Your example adds one extra `\n` at the end of the file, but that's all. (and that may be a bug, OP may not want that extra newline). And if this program is run on Windows, the file will have "\r\n" in it. "\n" is translated on write.